# Noise echo issue with Agora Web SDK in React JS (Basic Video Call)

Tags: reactjs, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora

I am developing an agora based web application for the video calling. I am using the Agora Basic video call example for the demo purpose in react js.
[Agora Basic Video Call Example](https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples-Web/tree/main/Demo/basicVideoCall)
I am facing the echo issue while joining the agora call.
I have tried multiple solution available to internet but I have not get any success. Can anyone help me?

I had already used:

```
localTracks.audioTrack = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack({
  encoderConfig: "music_standard",
  microphoneId: currentMic.deviceId,
  aec: true // Enable echo cancellation
});

//...

client.setAudioProfile("speech_standard"); // Set the audio profile
client.setParameters('{"che.audio.enable_aec": 1}'); // Enable AEC

//...

rtc.setLocalAudioEchoCancellation(true);
```

and so on...